# ¿Como puedo hacer un menu con submenu desplegable en asp.net?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Como puedo realizar un submenu dentro de un menú, trato de realizar uno pero no logro conseguirlo.

tengo esta lista

```
<div id="teaser">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="image"></div>
             
                    <div id="Div1">
                         <div id="Div2"  class="box">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a href="/Mantencion/Guias.aspx">Guías </a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Mantencion/Ensambles.aspx">Ensambles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Mantencion/Devoluciones.aspx">Devoluciones</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Mantencion/Clientes.aspx">Clientes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Consultas/Consultas.aspx">Consultas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Mantencion/Parametros.aspx">Parámetros</a></li>
                                  <li
                              </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>

            
        </div>
    </div>
```

y lo que estoy tratando de hacer es crear un nuevo "li"
que despliege como submenu estos:

```
<li><a href="/Mantencion/Clientes.aspx">Clientes</a></li>
<li><a href="/Mantencion/Parametros.aspx">Parámetros</a></li>
```

Porfavor ayuda!
Codigo actual:

https://jsfiddle.net/us28bmyo/1/#&togetherjs=eGnIMn6w45

Comment: estas usando bootstrap?, agrega los stilos para poder ayudarte

Comment: Como tu pregunta es más de CSS/HTML se necesita ver cómo estás armando y si podes colocar un ejemplo (podrías utilizar [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/) para armar un ejemplo sencillo y poder ayudarte sobre el mismo)

Comment: se hace con bootstrap, con los tags nav, navbar por ejemplo e incluso pueden hacer menus dinamicos combinando con razor

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/us28bmyo/1/#&togetherjs=eGnIMn6w45 aqui estoy tratando de realizar el submenu